# GCDAsyncSocket.h not found in LIFXKit framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoaasyncsocket

I installed LIFXKit from cocoapods, those are my pods:

```
pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'
pod 'LIFXKit'
```

When I build, I have this error :

[image]

I used @import CocoaAsyncSocket; in my Bridging-Header.h but no luck

PS : im using last xcode with swift 3